# getting table heading name using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

How can I get the column heading name of the corresponding cell clicked using jquery plugin: [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn)

```
$("#voterTable").on('click-cell.bs.table', function(field, value, row, element) {
      console.log(field);
   });
```

I have tried something like this, but it gives an object and I couldn't find the column heading property. I have also tried finding column heading in element and value argument but couldn't find the column heading property.